# Laravel Delete File Before Uploading New One

Tags: laravel

Following a tutorial, I was able to upload the file but when I upload another one, it adds the new file to the folder. I want to delete the file first before a user can upload a new one.

Why is it that this returns `File Not Exist` event if I am sure that the file exists in `/uploads/images/nerison123_1581390807.PNG`

```
// Get current user
$user = User::findOrFail(auth()->user()->id);
$image_path = $user->profile_image;

//delete the file first if it exists before uploading the new one
if (file_exists($image_path)) {
    @unlink($image_path);
} else {
    echo $image_path;
    echo "<br>";
    return "FILE NOT EXIST";
}
```

Comment: should it be instead `if (file_exists($image_path)) {` ?

Comment: what is the full path?

Comment: @Erich yes it is `$image_path` it was a wrong paste.

Comment: @TsaiKoga in my computer its `D:\LaravelImageUpload\public\uploads\images`

Comment: and what is `$image_path`?

Comment: @TsaiKoga $image_path is from the users table where the image is located. `/uploads/images/nerison123_1581390807.PNG`

Comment: @beginner is that the relative path from the `/public` web root?  or the project source directory?

Comment: @Erich yes it is from the public folder. I created `uploads` folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `public_path()` to change `image_path` to full_path:

```php
    if (file_exists(public_path($image_path))) {
        @unlink(public_path($image_path));
    } else {
        echo $image_path;
        echo "<br>";
        return "FILE NOT EXIST";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   $image = $request->file('image');
        $slug = str_slug($request->title);
        if (isset($image))
        {
            $currentDate = Carbon::now()->toDateString();
            $imagename = $slug.'-'.$currentDate.'-'. uniqid() .'.'. $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $image_resize = Image::make($image->getRealPath());   
            $image_resize->resize(1600,1066);
            if (!file_exists('storage/uploads/post'))
            {
                mkdir('storage/uploads/post',0777,true);
            }
            unlink('storage/uploads/post/'.$post->image);
            $image_resize->save('storage/uploads/post/'.$imagename);
        }else{
            $imagename = $post->image;
        }
```